# Does symmetry of second derivatives implies continuity?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to learn calculus of several variables, and well there's a theorem which says that if all partials up to the second order are continuous then $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y\partial x}$ holds. Well i was wondering if the converse is also true, that is if continuity would be neccesary for them to be equal.

my guess is no, since the proposition doesn't say "if and only if" but there's a misleading remark in the book i'm using which states "Exercise 3.16 shows that continuity of $D_{i}D_{j}f$ and $D_{j}D_{i}f$ at $a$ are neccesary for their equality there." but in the exercise there's nothing to prove.

Answer (score 2):

No, this fails already in 1D. In 1D all [Hessian matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) are $1\times 1$ matrices, and hence trivially symmetric, but not necessarily continuous. To see a higher-dimensional counterexample, consider a diagonal (and therefore symmetric) Hessian, where (at least one) diagonal entry is a copy of the 1D counterexample.

Comment: What is a Hessian matrix in $1D$? (Since a 1 by 1 matrix is just a number) An example might be helpful

Comment: I updated the answer.